# The entire content of my Wordpress page has disappeared

Tags: pages, errors, content

I have a blog installed on my site using Wordpress. Last week I upgraded Wordpress from 2.6 to 3.0.4 (I had to do this manually).

All went well, or so I thought, but I have just noticed that the content of an existing page has vanished. The page URL still works, but all content has disappeared - doctype, html tags, body tags, everything.

Please note, this is specific to pages - posts are still displaying fine.

I have since created a brand new page which does not display the content either.

Things I have tried include

```
* Switching to a freshly installed theme
* Reverting the page to an older version
* Deactivating all plugins
* Setting the problem page to draft, and back again
* Deleting the .htaccess file
```

I suspect it's a database problem and have contacted my hosting company who have said the only thing they can do is restore the DB from a backup, but that I should consider it a last resort.

Does anyone have any further ideas what to try?

Comment: We'd need to see your site ... but the content should still be in the database.  Is there any way you can look at the DB directly with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I can dive into phpMyAdmin, yes, and the content is still in there.

Comment: have you tried resetting permalinks?

Comment: If its just one page... did you check to see what the Page Template was set to, and that that file exists? Although, I just checked the page link and its appears to be working, so maybe either (a) you've already figured out and fixed the problem, or (b) you were having a problem that was cached in your browser. Can you report back what the answer was, so others can learn from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions - the page is now back up and running, but I am not certain why.

My theory is that I actually fixed it by deleting the .htaccess file which I removed from the root of `/public_html` and assumed would be recreated by Wordpress.

It's not been replaced in the `/public_html` folder, but without me noticing a .htaccess file was created in the `/public_html/blog` folder (where the blog is kept).

As I didn't notice this at first I can't be certain this was the solution, but it is my best guess.

Comment: Good to know that your problem was solved. Can you [click the "accept" to indicate you don't need another answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Welcome to this site, and I hope to see more good questions and answers from you in the future!